# Умножение полиномов по модулю 2

Tags: python-3.x

Как реализовать умножение полиномов по модулю 2?

```
1 1 0 0 1
   1 1 0 0 1 
       1 1 0 0 1
          1 1 0 0 1 
             1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 -> это ответ
```

Не получается функцию написать на питоне.

Comment: У меня есть два полинома 1+x+x^4 и 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 . Вот и я умножаю 1 на 2 по модулю 2. То есть если столбце есть 1+1=0 1+1+1=1 0+1=1 0+0=0

Comment: редактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каждому полиному поставим в соответствие число. Первый полином - 10011 как двоичное число, оно же равно 19. Второе 11111=31. Нужна сумма по модулю 2 первого числа со сдвигом для каждой цифры второго числа.

```
n1 = input("Введите первое двоичное число: ")
n2 = input("Введите второе двоичное число: ")

n1 = int(n1,2)
s=int('0',2)
for c in n2[::-1]:
    if(c=='1'):
        s=s^n1
    n1*=2
print(bin(s))
```

Comment: Мой ответ должен получиться 1+x^4+x^6+x^7+x^8. А как вы говорите ответ не получается. Это помехоустойчивое кодирование. G(x) полином

Comment: У меня не только произведения, а по модулю 2.

Comment: Ответ изменила. Получается 0b111010001, что и соответствует ожидаемому.

Comment: Я так долго мучался. У меня код знаете 37 строк, а вы за 10. Спасибо за работу

Comment: @HasmikGarkyaka могу ли я создать список list = ['0111000','1011100','0100000'] и умножить каждый элемент на 100010111 используя эту функцию

Comment: Можете. Сделайте вызов в цикле.